# Using mocks in Karate DSL feature file with stanalone run

Tags: karate

I have REST service, written in language different from Java.
It have few dependencies from other REST services.

For example service under development and testing is **A**, other services are respectively **B** and **C**.

I want to run system test for **A**, some tests require **B** or/and **C** to be online and perform queries from **A**.

I wrote b-mock.featue and c-mock.feature to represent that services in mock.

Also I wrote some a-test-smth.feature files to run test against **A**

Is it possible to add some information into a-test-smth.feature to enable some mocks for concrete test?

Now I should run standalone karate.jar twice, first - for mocking. second - for run tests. That approach works, but, I can't ceck that:

- some API calls to **A** not required **B** or **C**
- can't emulate service **B** down or for example slow or incorrect response answer fetching

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using Java ? If so then the best approach is to perform the set-up of your test in Java code.  You can start 2 mocks for B and c and *then* start the main test for your service A. And at the end do clean-up if needed.

You can refer this as an example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#consumer-provider-example

Row 3 shows how you can start a mock and run a Karate test.

If you are not using Java and would like to use *only* the stand-alone JAR, it is actually possible using Java-interop and quite easy, I just tried it.

EDIT: This API is now built into Karate, so you don't need to write the extra JS code below: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#within-a-karate-test

### (Obsolete)

First create this bit of JavaScript code that is smart enough to start a Karate mock:

```
function() {
  var Mock = Java.type('com.intuit.karate.netty.FeatureServer');
  var file = new java.io.File('src/test/java/mock/web/cats-mock.feature');
  var server = Mock.start(file, 0, false, null);
  return server.port;
}
```

And this is how it can look in the `Background` of your main Karate test. You can see how you can do some conditional logic if needed and you have plenty of ways to change things based on your environment.

```
Background:
    * def starter = read('start-mock.js')
    * def port = karate.env == 'mock' ? starter() : 8080
    * url 'http://localhost:' + port + '/cats'
```

Does this answer your question ? Let me know and I will add this trick to the documentation !

Comment: Yes I am not using Java in project where I wish to use Karate DSL. 
Java-interop works fine, and provided solution worked as expected! Thanks a lot!

There is one more thing, related to running test cases. Now(after I use JS for start mock before test), test didn't finished with exit code, it freezes, like in case when I run simple mock. And I need to abort it by hands.

I wold like to use it in CI, so there is need of exit to be completed gracefully. I think that it could be handler called after scenarios, that closes mock.

Is that possible?

Comment: @KonstantinMalinin you can quit a mock gracefully by a simple GET, please try and let me know: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#stopping - if that does not work, you can call `stop()` on the server reference